# Limiting the number of lines within a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm well aware this question has been asked but I cannot find a valid answer.
Using a combination of prior solutions I've come up with this code:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)string
{
    int numLines = notesTextView.contentSize.height / notesTextView.font.lineHeight;
        if (numLines <= 8)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

This does not work because the number of lines is counted prior to the additional text so we are still taken a line beyond what we want and are then trapped on it as no further editing is possible.

I've also tried solutions that detect "\n" entries but this doesn't work either as we can reach new lines naturally without pressing return.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment, was my answer helpful or it did not work for you?

Comment: It didn't work for me. It would either dismiss the textview once return was pressed or when I removed that bit of the code would take the cursor to the beginning of the 10th line before not allowing any further input (I'd like this to happen at the end of the 8th line).

Comment: Just edited my answer. Check the new method and see if that one works for you.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I've tried "\n" solutions. They work until you reach a new line without pressing return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also encountered this problem. None of the earlier solutions worked well for me. Here is my solution, hope: (iOS 7+ only!)

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [textView layoutManager];
    NSUInteger numberOfLines, index, numberOfGlyphs = [layoutManager numberOfGlyphs];
    NSRange lineRange;
    for (numberOfLines = 0, index = 0; index < numberOfGlyphs; numberOfLines++)
    {
            (void) [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:index
                                               effectiveRange:&lineRange];
        index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
    }

    if (numberOfLines > 3)
    {
        // roll back
        _labelField.text = _text;
    }
    else
    {
        // change accepted
        _text = _labelField.text;
    }
}
```

It uses an NSString ivar _text to be able to roll back after the text has been changed. This does not cause any flickering.

numberOfLines reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001810-CJBGBIBB

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *temp = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]
    CGSize size = [temp sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width,999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    int numLines = size.height / textView.font.lineHeight;
    if (numLines <= 8)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Parse in the new text, then check the new text's size using the textView's information.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. A lone "\n" character does not appear to change the height of "size" so we have the same problem as my solution.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought it would default the linebreak mode, but apparently not.  Check out the edit, add the `lineBreakMode` option to the size method.

Comment: It doesn't work for natural line changes either, it stops accepting new input midway through the 9th line. Can't figure out why that happens tbh.

Comment: Same problem with line-break mode. No matter what I try we're brought to the 9th line and subsequently trapped there.

Comment: What is the value of numLines in these situations?  Is it correct?  If it's not correct could it be that font.lineHeight is not correct?  Create another size struct and get the size.height of a single character (something like [@"a" sizeWithFont...).

Comment: It's 8 up until we type a character on to that line, as with my solution it gives us the number of lines prior to the latest character. I think the font.lineheight is correct it's the size.height which doesn't update when given a \n charecter but I'll take a look in to it.

Comment: Log out the `temp` string that gets created.  It should be the string you are trying to set it to (after the update).  If it's not then something is wrong.

Comment: The temp string is exactly as it should be I think the /n character is not counted as being on a new line but is counted as being the end of the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

here is how i have done it in past, i hope it provide you with some help.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text 
{

// limit the number of lines in textview
NSString* newText = [mytextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

// pretend there's more vertical space to get that extra line to check on
CGSize tallerSize = CGSizeMake(mytextView.frame.size.width-15, mytextView.frame.size.height*2); 

CGSize newSize = [newText sizeWithFont:mytextView.font constrainedToSize:tallerSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

if (newSize.height > mytextView.frame.size.height)
{
    NSLog(@"two lines are full");
    return NO;
}


// dismiss keyboard and send comment
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    [mytextView resignFirstResponder];

    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

good luck.

Edit:

Ok try the following method and see if this works for you. Just change the number of lines to whatever number you want.

```
 (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if([text isEqualToString:@"n"]) {
        rows++;
    if(rows >= maxNumberOfLines){
        //Exit textview
         return NO;
        }
   }
  return YES;
```

Let me know if this works out.

Comment: Removing the keyboard dismissal, which disables me from pressing pressing return with the purpose to start a new line at all, this gets me to the 10th line then refuses to take any input for that line. Thanks all the same.