# UITextView if line numbers is 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

Is there is anyway to check the number of lines in a UITextview?

I searched on the internet but I found nothing.

Comment: first search result on google, you made no effort to find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837348/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textview-lines-wrapped-by-frame-size

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171847/limiting-the-number-of-lines-within-a-uitextview

Comment: -1 close this question

Comment: duplicated. Have some time to google, buddy ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Count the number of lines of text

```
int numLines = textView.contentSize.height / textView.font.lineHeight;
NSLog(@"number of line - %d", numLines);
```

And for [iOS 7 see this Question/Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123022/uitextview-number-of-lines-ios-7)

**EDIT for iOS < 7:**

This is proper answer

```
UIFont *myFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]; // your font with size
CGSize size = [textView.text sizeWithFont:myFont  constrainedToSize:textView.frame.size  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; // default mode
int numLines = size.height / myFont.lineHeight;
NSLog(@"number of line - %d", numLines);
```

Comment: content size can be different depending on the frame, this will not give you the right results

Comment: @Basheer_CAD - I checked by this code with diff. frame of UITextView, It's working for me .. Thanks :)

Comment: contentSize won't always work correctly because if you fill a text view with more text than fits in its frame, the content might or might not enable scrolling, depending on the settings.

Comment: @DuncanC - Yes this is not working all time so I edited my answer.. please check it.

Comment: @iPatel, don't forget that sizeWithFont is deprecated, you have to update your answer by saying this ;)

Comment: @Basheer_CAD - I already put solution for iOS 7.

Comment: now its the charm then :)

Answer (score 3):

For iOS7, a version that take care that you can have differents font (and font size) in your UITextView :

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfLines
{
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [textView layoutManager];
    NSUInteger index, numberOfLines;
    NSRange glyphRange = [layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:[textView textContainer]];
    NSRange lineRange;

    for (numberOfLines = 0, index = glyphRange.location; index < glyphRange.length; numberOfLines++){
        (void) [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:index
                                               effectiveRange:&lineRange];
        index = NSMaxRange(lineRange);
    }
    return numberOfLines;
}
```

Comment: For more info, Apple docs for this method is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't search a lot, here's a way :

```
CGSize size = [myString sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width,999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
int numLines = size.height / textView.font.lineHeight;
```

Comment: `sizeWithFont` is deprecated, consider using `sizeWithAttributes` and `boundingRectWithSize`.

Comment: @JMarsh, sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: is deprecated in iOS 7, but is the **CORRECT** way to do it in iOS < 7 (the alternative, boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:, is ONLY available in iOS 7.) Thus rdurand's approach is quite reasonable for an app that runs on iOS < 7 as well as iOS 7.

Comment: @DuncanC : thanks (lol). JMarsh : you're correct, and there certainly are other ways, this is *a* way to do it.